# Uploading images to another site hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I have a solution with MVC and WebAPI projects. They are both hosted in IIS as, for example: http:/mvc.com/ and http:/webapi.com/ .
When WebApi recieves images, it saves them at Content/Images/ folder of WebAPI folder using the path generated by the following line of code:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Content/Images/<imagename>.jpg");
```

How do I configure things to get it saved in Content/Images/ folder of mvc project ? 
I try to compose the following path:

```
@"http:\mvc.com\Content\Images"
```

But I get error: URI formats are not supported
And when it's like this:

```
@"mvc.com\Content\Images"
```

I get error: "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a folder outside both projects and share that folder between the two.

You can make a setting in your web.config to save the directory path in. This code works for either solution (whether you keep the images in one project or external).

Add this to your *web.config* file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="imageFolder" value="C:\somewhere"/>
</appSettings>
```

And this to your C# file to get the location:

```
var wc = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
string folderPath = wc.AppSettings.Settings["imageFolder"]?.Value;
```